# JMeter - CLI/Command Line - How do I generate the exact same output files that are produced in GUI mode?

Tags: jmeter

In GUI mode I have output files that are generated, these files are configured in the "Write Results to File" field. But when running in CLI it's not generating these.
Why is this?
How do I make CLI mode produce the exact same output files?

I expected the output files to be there but they weren't.

Comment: Can you provide screenshot of the Listener? What you mean by there (/bin) ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid we need more details, like:

1. What exact [Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-listeners) you're using
2. How it's configured
3. What do you expect to see in the results file
4. What does [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) say

For example when I add a [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) and tell it to store the results into a file named `foo.bar` JMeter properly generates the output file in non-GUI mode:

[image]